# NFL rules, overtime, double turnover

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl

NFL overtime rules. Say first possession offense throws an interception but then the defender fumbles trying  to make a return, and the offense gets it back. The offense gets a new set of downs due to possession changing, so if they go down and kick a field goal is the game over? Or does the opposing team still get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the answer is yes, the game is over because the team that kicked off first has had their possession.

I base this on this description of a “double change of possession” source is the [NFL Rules](https://operations.nfl.com/the-rules/nfl-rulebook/#article-5-general-rules-applicable-to-overtime), Rule 16 (Overtime), article 5.a. note 3.

Note that “the situation” is about a foul by the defense prior to a turnover. The offense could take the penalty, and then there is no turnover and the initial possession continues.  But what about a turnover during the return of a turnover, which is your question.

(Bolding added by me)

> The situation in (2) may also affect the team that receives the opening kickoff during its first possession. If there is a foul by the second team followed by a double change of possession, and the first team accepts the result of the play, **the second team has had its required possession, and the first team has possession of the ball for the second time.** However, if it accepts the penalty, it will extend its initial possession.